# template or member function selection

Tags: c++, templates

I've been trying to understand the way C++ selects templates or member functions.
Consider the following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Test
{
    template<typename X>
    explicit Test( X&& s){ std::cout << "1" << std::endl;}
    
    explicit Test( const std::string& s) { std::cout << "2"<< std::endl; }
    explicit Test( std::string&& s) { std::cout << "3"<<  std::endl; }

};

int main ()
{
    std::string line = "TEST";
    Test test( line );
}
```

I'm getting "1" printed on console. Why "2" is not selected if it is a non-template that matches the parameter types?

Comment: Basically the template is a better match because it uses universal references. It can sometimes lead to surprising results. So you have to use them carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor template's parameter is declared as forwarding reference. When being passed an lvalue such as `line`, the template parameter `X` is deduced as `std::string&`, and after reference collapsing the parameter type is `std::string&`, i.e. an lvalue-reference to non-const `std::string`. It's an exact match and wins in overload resolution.

On the other hand, the constructor taking `const std::string&` requires const-qualifying the argument, and the constructor taking `std::string&&` can't be used with lvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your templated constructor is selected instead of the non-templated ones has already been explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64842222/8012646).

However, note that you can still rely on [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) for disabling your templated constructor for `std::string` arguments:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_string_v = std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::string>;
```

Then, in your `Test` class, add an unnamed template parameter to your templated constructor:

```
struct Test
{
    template<typename X, typename = std::enable_if_t<!is_string_v<X>>>
    explicit Test( X&& s){ std::cout << "1" << std::endl;}
    
    explicit Test( const std::string& s) { std::cout << "2"<< std::endl; }
    explicit Test( std::string&& s) { std::cout << "3"<<  std::endl; }
    
};
```

This way:

```
int main ()
{
   std::string line;
   Test test(line);    // selects 2

   const std::string cStr;
   Test testStr(cStr); // selects 2

   int i{};
   Test testInt(i);    // selects 1

   float f{};
   Test testFloat(f);  // selects 1
}
```

With C++20 concepts, you can very likely end up writing something more readable and expressive.